# custom orderBy() on constraining eager loads?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

my question is about the possibilty of customizing Laravel's orderBy() method of the query builder, which i am using to sort an eager loaded dataset.

This is the query scope I am using to generate the dataset. Everything works fine so far with this.

```
 public function scopeRestaurantsWithMenusToday($query, $city_uri){

    return $query->where('city_uri', '=', $city_uri)->with([
        'restaurants',
        'restaurants.menusToday' => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('date', 'asc');
        }
    ]);

}
```

What I want to achieve is an advanced 'asc' of the used orderBy() method in the eager load constraint of 'restaurants.menusToday':

1. first all restaurants where "date == today"
2. then all restaurants where "date != today"

Can somebody help me out? Thx!

Comment: See if you can even get that query to work in normal SQL. Then see if you can translate that into Eloquent. My first thought is select all results with today's date then union them with those of not today's date, but there's probably a better way than that.

Comment: thought of that too, thx. just wanted to keep this as solution if no "elegant" Laravel solution is possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work... the idea is to add an additional select which is 0 or 1 depending on if the date is today.  Then you can order by that column first, then the actual date second.

```
public function scopeRestaurantsWithMenusToday($query, $city_uri){

    return $query->where('city_uri', '=', $city_uri)->with([
        'restaurants',
        'restaurants.menusToday' => function($query) {
            $query->addSelect(\DB::raw('if(DATE(`date`) = CURDATE(), 1, 0) as is_current_date'))->orderBy(\DB::raw('is_current_date'), 'DESC')->orderBy('date');
        }
    ]);

}
```

Comment: thx @user3158900, I add tried another solution which I posted right now, but also failed. if all that does not work, I'll (try :)) to use your sql statement. thx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement like @user3158900 suggested until I found out another problem with this that makes it quite complicated and difficult to manage then.

Here I found out a new way, simply by setting an attribue in the Restaurant model, informing about whether the restaurant has menus today (=1) or not (=0), then using this attribute in the orderBy() method. So far so good :). So I startet to use attribute setters and getters, but I don't get it working.

This - as a test of Collection integration - works just fine:

```
class Restaurant extends Model {
     protected $appends = ['menusTodayCheck' => 'thisTestWorks'];}
```

The collection returns an array "menusTodayCheck => 'thisTestWorks" in the appends part.

Does anybody know why these ways using $appends and get...() don't work?

1st fail)

```
class Restaurant extends Model {
protected $appends = ['menusTodayCheck'];

public function getMenusTodayCheckAttribute()
{
    return 'thisTestDoesntWork';
}}
```

The collection returns an array "0 => menusTodayCheck" in the appends part.

2nd fail)

```
class Restaurant extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['menusTodayCheck' => function() {
    return "thisTestDoesntWork";}];}
```

This one even throws an error: unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)